# Can't use foundation on Middleman via bower

Tags: ruby, sprockets, middleman

I want to use foundation in my middleman project, is a brand new project.

On the middleman [documentation](https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/asset_pipeline/) they say:

> Sprockets supports Bower, so you can add your Bower components path
>   directly:

```
sprockets.append_path File.join root, 'bower_components'
```

So i added that code above to my config.rg

Then they say:

> To make your bower controlled assets - images, fonts etc. - available
>   within your application, you need to import them using
>   sprockets.import_asset

so i added in my config.rb this:

```
sprockets.import_asset 'foundation'
```

Then i try to see if foundation is working, so I added this to my index.html:

```
<a href="#" class="button">Default Button</a>
```

I have also required in all.js foundation like this:

```
//= require foundation.js
//= require_tree .
```

And on the all.css like this:

```
@import "foundation";
```

But i get this error:

```
 x GET http://localhost:4567/stylesheets/foundation 
all.js:704 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Finally my project structure is this:

[image: project structure]

what im i doing wrong ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to require jQuery before you require foundation.js, as foundation depends on jQuery.

Amend your code like so:

```
//= require_tree .
//= require foundation.js
```

However, I prefer to explicitly call vendor files so I am not including anything I don't need. So my app.js file starts like this (depending on how you decided to include jQuery in your bower_components folder):

```
//= require jquery/dist/jquery
//= require foundation
```